# How this test prove my application is vulnerable to clickjacking attacks?

Tags: penetration-test

I have downloaded the "Clickjackingtool" and done the followings steps.

Step 1:- I have opened the clickjackingtool and paste the URL and click GO button(Image 1).

Step 2:- I have opened the clickjackingtool and paste the URL and set the width and height and click GO button(Image 2).

[image: I have opened the clickjackingtool and paste the URL and click GO button]

[image: I have opened the clickjackingtool and paste the URL and set the width and height and click GO button]

When i set the frame size(Width and height{2nd image}),My application is size is minimized.

how can i believe my application is strong or not?

Please help me i am new this type testing.

Answer (score 1):

Your application was framed into the other application, if you allow framing of your application (unless from certain domains only) you are vulnerable to clickjacking.

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough to block all writing actions while in a frame?

Comment: That's also a possibility, I always recommend not allowing it as often there is not really a reason to allow other sites to frame it. If you do need that you could just block writing actions. I wasn't even aware that was possible.